# Google App Engine local development server SSL warning (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ssl

Each time I upload my app to Google App Engine, the logs always show this warning:

```
WARNING appengine_rpc.py:435 ssl module not found. Without the ssl
module, the identity of the remote host cannot be verified, and
connections may NOT be secure. To fix this, please install the ssl
module from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssl .
```

I'm running a `virtualenv` with Python 2.7. When I'm in it, I try to run

```
$ pip install ssl
```

but this produces an error:

```
ValueError: This extension should not be used with Python 2.6 or later 
(already built in), and has not been tested with Python 2.3.4 or earlier.
```

If `ssl` is built in to Python 2.7, how do I tell the local development server to use the built in `ssl` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like appcfg.py is not using your virtualenv correctly.  You can try editing the appcfg.py script so that it prints sys.version and sys.path, to confirm that it's using your virtualenv correctly.  (The shebang line is "#!/usr/bin/env python", so that should use your active environment, but it's worth checking.)

If you're using the Launcher, you need to tell it explicitly where to look for your virtualenv's Python.  Go to Preferences, and set the Python Path to your virtualenv's Python 2.7.  The Launcher prints which Python path it is using in the Logs (at least when starting the dev server).